# problem in loading an file in java fx in netbeans ide

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to load an image file in javafx main class. i've commented all the lines in my class but still getting an error. i think the image is not loading from the path. What should be done in this matter?

```
        Image img=new Image("‪\"\\\\C:\\\\Users\\\\Avi\\\\Desktop\\\\test.jpg\"");
        sp_mainlayout = new StackPane();  
        cc_custom = new CustomControl();
                Pane back=new HBox(15);
        sp_mainlayout.getChildren().add(cc_custom);
                back.getChildren().add(new ImageView(img));




    }


    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


        primaryStage.setTitle("Chess game");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(sp_mainlayout, 1000, 1020));
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

The exception the programme is showing.

```
Exception in Application init method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application init method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:912)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1118)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:620)
    at project.template.ChessApplication.init(ChessApplication.java:52)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:841)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)
    ... 5 more
Exception running application project.template.ChessApplication
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: What happens if you use `"file:///C:/Users/Avi/Desktop/test.jpg"`?

Comment: yeah... that trick works. Thanks

Comment: That worked because it was a valid, absolute _URL_ (with a `file` scheme).